# "Call to undefined function views_get_view()" error

Tags: views

What do I need to load before calling `views_get_view()`?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you just need to have [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module enabled to have this function globally available. You enable/disable modules at `/admin/modules`.

Comment: I don't see there a module named "Views", are that module enabled by default?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/views Views is contrib. Not in core until D8.